# How to show pop message before majorupgrade

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

How to show pop message to user that he really wants to upgrade new installer or not before Major upgrade.

I tried with MajorUpgrade Element, able to do only downgrade custom actions not major upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the `MajorUpgrade` element a `WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED` property will be defined when an upgrade is to be performed. Then you can define a new dialog or pop-up in your UI based on that property. You'd need to modify the `Publish` element where you want to put the UI like so:

```
<Publish Event='ShowMajorUpgradeDialog'>WIX_UPGRADE_DETECTED</Publish>
```